# Integrabilty of distibutions

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, weak-derivatives

Let $T : D(\Omega) \to \mathbb R$, be a generalised function. What can we say about its integrability? For example, does it belong to $L^p(\mathbb R)$? I am interested in the case of non-regular distributions.

This question arose while studying Sobolev spaces. Let $f \in W^{k, p}(\mathbb R)$. So its weak derivatives up to the order $k$ are in $L^p(\mathbb R)$. What does it mean for them to be in $L^p(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: If $g \in L^p$ then $g \in L^1_{loc}$ so $\int_0^x g(y)dy$ is well-defined and continuous. That $f$ has a weak derivative means $f = f(0)+\int_0^. g(y)dy$ in $L^1_{loc}$ ie. $\int_{-a}^a |f(x)-f(0)-\int_0 g(y)dy|dx=0$ and $\int_{-a}^a |g(x)|dx < \infty$ for every $a$. Taking a sequence of mollifiers you are asking if $(f \ast \phi_n)'$ converges in $L^1_{loc}$..

Comment: Are you trying to explain the case when representation exists?

Comment: For $f \in L^1_{loc}$ you should probably look carefully at $g_n = (f\ast \phi_n)' $ where $ \phi_n(x) = n \phi(nx),\phi(x) = (1-|x|) 1_{|x| < 1}$ then $f$ has a weak derivative iff $g_n \to g$ in $L^1_{loc}$. Otherwise $g_n$ converges only in the sense of distributions (or $(W_{loc}^{1,\infty})'$) to $f$' distributional derivative. If $g \in L^p$ then $g_n \to g$  in $L^p$.

Comment: so if $g_n$ converge only in sense of distributions, then $g$ is not locally integrable and so it is not in $L^p$?

Comment: @AlPrihodko: The concept of "generalized functions" may have sesveral interpretations, so you should specify first which one you use. Do you mean "Schwartz distributions" or maybe "elements of Sobolev spaces"?